# Resizing SVG image in MediaWiki

Tags: image, svg, mediawiki, scale

We display SVG images in MediaWiki using a template with this code:

```
{{#tag:svgfile||src={{{1}}}|height={{{height|300px}}}|width={{{width|600px}}}}}
```

where {{{1}}} is the uploaded file.

Now we want to be able to rescale the image, just like we do with JPGs, etc, using:

```
[[Image:<file name>.JPG|200px]]
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Our current workaround is simply to recreate the SVG (in Visio) at a different size which is quite time consuming!

**Update:** code on page is:

```
<p><b>{{SVG|Bitmap VS SVG.svg|height=300px|width=400px}}</b></p>
<p>
    <a class="external autonumber" href="<url>index.php?title=Special:Upload&amp;wpDestFile=Bitmap VS SVG.svg">
        <iframe src="/mediawiki/images/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg" width="400px" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </a> 
    <a href="/mediawiki/index.php/Image:Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg" title="Image:Bitmap VS SVG.svg">desc</a>
</p>
```

Comment: What does the template end up rendering like as HTML?  Does it use display inline HTML5 style, or as an object, or is it referenced from an image tag?

Comment: @robertc - thanks for the reply. I don't know how to answer your question - what should I look for?

Comment: When you're looking at the results of the template in a web browser, what is the source code?

Comment: @robertc - I'll check after the weekend and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: @robertc - can you explain what you mean by source code in this case? Do I need something like Firebug? Or do you mean the code in the page, which is: **{{SVG|Bitmap VS SVG.svg|height=300px|width=400px}}**

Comment: I mean the source code of the web page that the browser is seeing, that you get by right clicking on the page and doing 'View Source'.  What you've got there is not 'code in the page'. it is wiki markup, this is not something that can be displayed by a browser.  The server translates your wiki markup into HTML which is then sent to the browser.  If the functionality to display scaled SVG is not already built in to MediaWiki then solving this will require making changes to PHP code.  If the functionality to display them *is* built in to MediaWiki then this is the wrong place to be asking.

Comment: @robertc - got it, thanks. I've added the code to the question. I can't see anything about scaling there.

Comment: It's rendering the SVG inside an IFRAME element which, by the look of it, is set to the width and height you've specified.  There may be a way to make the SVG image always match the container size, I'll have a play around and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are two parts to this solution and I can only help you with the first part, but here it is:

Browsers (Firefox, Chrome & Opera) will resize the image to fit the available space if you remove the explicit size from the SVG file and replace it with a `viewBox`.  Here's what that Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg file on Wikipedia has at the top of it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1063" height="638">
```

And here's what it needs to be for automatic scaling:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1063 638">
```

You can see the difference in the context of the `iframe` as generated by your template above [in this example page](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/iframe-test.html).

Now the second part of this is how you can get it all to work on MediaWiki, and for that I can be less help.  I signed up for a Wikipedia account to try some stuff out but the default file embedding just creates a PNG version of the image, and it didn't seem like your particular template was available.  So to get this working for you, you're now going to need the help of someone who understands MediaWiki templates.

Comment: @robertc - wow, thanks for looking into this for me. I will check this out and get back to you asap.

Comment: @robertc - thanks so much for investigating for me. When I changed my template and you suggested it did not work - I could not even see viewBox in the page code. I noticed that rescaling *does* work on Wikipedia so I will need to investigate why it works there. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkRobinson viewBox is in the _SVG_ code.  I think the rescaling on Wikipedia is done by creating PNGs of various sizes on the server, I thought that was what you were trying to get away from?

Comment: @robertc - Aha, got it thanks. Yes, that indeed does work when I **change the SVG code** itself. With one exception - when I include the same item twice on a page in two sizes it only uses one of the sizes (so both SVGs displayed same size). But that's not likely to happen! Thanks very much.

Comment: @robertc - it gets weirder. The size in the viewBox appear to be *inversely proportional* to the size shown in MediaWiki. So if I add a viewBox of 0 0 10 50 it is larger than 0 0 1000 5000!

Comment: @robertc - even weirder, every time I refresh the page in MediaWiki the image changes size!

Comment: @MarkRobinson The viewBox should represent the default size of the image, once you've set it you shouldn't need to change it, it's there to provide the browser with information about how big the image _should_ be so that it can make correct decisions about scaling it to fit.  So you should specify the viewBox in your SVG, upload it once, then display the same SVG in different sized 'boxes'.  With the viewBox specified the browser (if it supports SVG) will size the SVG to fit.  If you're uploading multiple versions with different viewBox specifications then you're back where you started.

Comment: @MarkRobinson And one more thing - MediaWiki itself may be interfering with what you're trying to achieve (display a single SVG at multiple resolutions) by processing the image on the server and sending PNGs instead, which in turn may explain the weird behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @robertc - thanks again for the info; I will check it out. On your last point, no I uploaded one version (you can only display one at a time) but *displayed* it twice on the same page with different size parameters.

Comment: @MarkRobinson OK, I was just a little confused by your mention of multiple viewBox parameters.  If you have Firebug installed then you can check whether you're getting SVG or PNG by right clicking on the image and selecting 'Inspect Element' and checking what the file extension is.

Comment: @robertc - thanks, yet again. Really appreciate it. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: @robertc - here's what inspect element gives: *<img width="512" height="307" border="0" src="/images/thumb/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg/512px-Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg.png" alt="File:Bitmap VS SVG.svg">* which looks like PNG.

Comment: @MarkRobinson Yes it does. You'll need to find someone who can figure out the processing in Mediawiki then.

Comment: @robertc - OK, thanks. I'll post back here if I can solve it. Thanks for your hard work here!

Answer (score 0):

6 years after the question has been answered, it works as expected :

```
[[Image:fooobar.svg|200x200px]]
```